# I am a (relatively) experienced Stack Exchange user. I would like clearer criteria for "quality posts" on Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion

I have had two instances where I've gotten an automated warning that my account may be suspended for asking questions that have been view as low quality. On most other Stack Exchange sites, I can figure out relatively quickly what to do to contribute well and maintain steady positive records.

I would like to become a better community member, but I am having trouble understanding the standards for what constitutes quality. I have read the ["how to ask good questions" page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), but I don't think this page provides particularly clear guidelines.

Examples of things I do to write quality posts

- State the language or API I'm using in the title
- Simplify examples with general objects so they could be read by a future user, not just paste my code in
- Bold the specific question I have
- Provide examples of things I have tried
- Ask questions that aren't "write this code for me" type questions
- Apply appropriate tags

Here's an example: *[Find the subset of observations that excludes missing values for two columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42338343/find-the-subset-of-observations-that-excludes-missing-values-for-two-columns)*

But I still get marked down. Sure, not in that case, but on no other Stack Exchange site do I ask questions and have such a mixed reaction.

Could someone who has more experience on Stack Overflow provide a more detailed account of what is important in a good post than the things I have stated or than are stated in the link?

Comment: Not sure I'm seeing anything noteworthy about that question; it's got a positive score and from what I can tell, it seems concise enough to be on-topic.  Note that I'm not versed in R, which may also be a saving grace in that you don't get a lot of, "this is a stupid question"-type votes on it for now...

Comment: The first question I could find with a down vote uses "Trump" as the example keyword. Now I can't prove that was the motivation but given the recent brouhaha it's not unthinkable. It might be best to choose keywords that are as neutral as possible. I'm also unfamiliar with R so the only other thing I can say on that one is you don't need to label your edits in the post. We can see a search history with the link below the post to the left of your name.

Comment: Your only visible post with a negative score is primarily opinion based, which is off topic. If you have deleted negative score posts you may want to check them against the list of off topic reasons here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic. The only general advice would be to also read the 3rd party links at the bottom of that "How to ask" page if you haven't already.

Comment: Your first and fourth points are not good ones; tags shouldn't be in titles, and **My Question** is completely unnecessary. *"I still get marked down. Sure, not in that case"* - then what use is it as an example?

Comment: Please don't make a habit of bolding your question. It should stand out without needing the extra formatting - as a separate paragraph in the beginning or end of the question. If you need the extra formatting so one can find the question in a WOT you posted, then the question is broken with or without the bf.

Comment: Obligatory reading material before asking an R question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/1412059